# How do you define a primary key on a table in Trino?

Tags: sql, trino

The query below does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (date varchar, id varchar, PRIMARY KEY (date,id))
```

I can't seem to find any docs on primary keys in Trino.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. As the [description](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview.html) says:

> Trino is a distributed SQL query engine designed to query large data sets distributed over one or more heterogeneous data sources.

Trino does not maintain primary keys, indexes and so on. See also [use cases](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview/use-cases.html) and [Trino concepts](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview/concepts.html).